# How can I enhance the output of find and grep?

Tags: text-processing, grep, find

I really don't look forward to having to do `find`/`grep` because the output, as returned by

```
find . -exec grep sometext {} \; -print
```

is just not very easy to read even when you dump it in a file.  What I would like is if the file name had an indentation of 0 and then each file line where a match was found were indented with the line number and each match is highlighted in color.

Let me know if this is possible.  I just can't read the awful output as it comes out of the command that I know.

I go between ksh and bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
grep --color=auto -r -n sometext *
```

Example output:

```
filename:10:    foo sometext bar
```

The first field is the filename, second field is the line number and `sometext` is colored.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe

```
find . -exec grep -H {} \;
```

Comment: "This is the default when there is more than one file to search" - `man grep`.

Comment: @jasonwryan his method only calls a single file at time, so there is only one file to search. Using `+` instead of `\;` would provide multiple files to grep, be more efficient, and is defined by POSIX.